# Returning values out of for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following function:

```
  function getId(a){
    var aL = a.length;
    for(i = 0; i < aL; i++ ){
      return a[i][2].split(":", 1)[0];
    }    
  }
```

and when using `console.log()` within the function instead of `return` I get all of the values in the loop, and the same goes for `document.write`.  How can I access these values as a string for use in another section of my code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `return` statement immediately exits a function, returning the value of the expression that follows it.  If you use a `return` statement in a loop without some sort of conditional like that it will preform the first pass and then exit. You need to collect them in a variable and return the variable after the loop.  As others have suggested you'll probably want to store them in an array.

Comment: Thanks Useless Code after looking into this a bit deeper I see where I was mistaken.  Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that with [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Generators_and_iterators_(merge_into_Iterators_and_Generators)) in newer versions of js, but that's out of question. Here's what you can do:

```
function getId(a){
  var aL = a.length;
  var values = [];
  for(i = 0; i < aL; i++ ){
    values.push(a[i][2].split(":", 1)[0]);
  }    
  return values.join('');
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `var values = [];`?

Comment: `yield` link is dead. New is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators. Can't edit due to full edit queue.

Answer (score 2):

You gotta cache the string and return later:

```
function getId(a){
    var aL = a.length;
    var output = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < aL; i++ ){
       output += a[i][2].split(":", 1)[0];
    }    
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The return statement **breaks** the loop once it is executed. Therefore
  consider putting the **return** statement **outside** the **loop**.
- Since you want to return a string, you will create a variable and
  assign it to an empty string.(This is where will append/add results
  from the loop.)
- return the string variable.

So final code will look like...

```
function getId(a){
    var result = '';
    var aL = a.length;
    for(i = 0; i < aL; i++ ){
      result += a[i][2].split(":", 1)[0];
    } 
    return result;
  }
```