# es6 for-in loop returns first object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

New to ES6 so I'm looking for a short replacement of `forEach()` and I've found [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/04/es6-in-depth-iterators-and-the-for-of-loop/).

**React:**

```
...

_productLoop(){
    for (var product of this.props.data) {
      const varient = product.variants.map(v => v);
      console.log(varient[0]);
      return(
        <tr>
          <td>{product.title}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    }
  }

 render(){
  return(
    <table>
      [...]
      <tbody>
        {this._productLoop()}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
 }

...
```

I have two arrays but only one object is showing for my loop. Any error here?

Comment: A `return` statement exits the function immediately. If you `return` inside a loop then the function will exit on the first iteration.

Comment: You return on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ahhh I see. If I place the return outside, my browser console blows up. How to properly structure this? Any docs for this?

Comment: The question says for-in but it is actually for-of, which is completely different beast. For such cases map-reduce constructions may be more straightforward (although less readable).

Comment: Im relatively new to the terms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning values out of for loop in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131838/returning-values-out-of-for-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement is breaking the loop. Besides that, the `return` statement *can't* concatenate what will be returned from the function. Once you execute `return`, you can't execute `return` again.

The solution is to create a string and concatenate the results with itself, then return it later. This is what you have expected.

**Edit**: I never written in react.js, but I'll update this answer soon. This isn't your case...

```
var result = "";

for (var product of this.props.data) {
    result += "\
        <tr>\
            <td>" + product.title + "</td>\
        </tr>";
}

return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're logging the `varient` (typo, by the way) for, but to start off with, you probably want something more like this:

```
...
 render() {
  return (
    <table>
      [...]
      <tbody>
        {this.props.data.map(product =>
          <tr>
            <td>{product.title}</td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
 }

...
```

Comment: I need this to be in a function :(

Comment: You can move `this.props.data.map...` to its own function as you had in your example.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using below code `this.props.data.map(showProduct)` to loop each of your props data and call the `showProduct` function and to show the title

```
render() {
  const showProduct = (item) => {
  return (<tr>
        <td>{product.title}</td>
      </tr>);
  };
  return (
    <table>
      [...]
      <tbody>
        {this.props.data.map(showProduct)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this to be in a function:

```
_productLoop(){
    let products = this.props.data.map(product => {
      let varient = product.variants.map(v => v);
      console.log(varient[0]);
      return(
        <tr key={product.id}>
          <td>{product.title}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    });
    return(<tbody>{products}</tbody>);
  }


render() {
  return (
    <table>
      [...]
      {this._productLoop()}
    </table>
  )
 }
```